# `\MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime ` has the `milliseconds` property also it doesn't have `milliseconds` property

Tags: php, mongodb, reflection

Can somebody please explain this behaviour? Or maybe send a relevant link that explains it?

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

$object = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(1);

$ro = new ReflectionObject($object);

foreach ($ro->getProperties() as $rp) {
    $rp->setAccessible(true);
    var_dump($rp->getValue($object));
}
```

Results in:

```
Warning: Undefined property: MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime::$milliseconds
```

Why does the reflection say that there is property 'milliseconds' and then says there is no property milliseconds? :-D

Thank you!

Comment: I can't answer the question directly, but BSON's UTC datetime is [defined](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html) as an int64 of milliseconds since the epoch, so milliseconds should be in there somewhere.